# Select iteratively and remove value once selected in R

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration

I have two corresponding vectors that I need to iterate through sequentially.  **Within each group**, I need to select the lowest value from the first vector and select the lowest value from the second vector.  I then need to remove the value selected from the second vector, and repeat the process for the second lowest number in the first vector.

Here is an example:

```
items <- (c("item 1","item 1","item 1","item 2","item 2","item 2","item 3","item 3","item 3"))
ordered <- (c(.5,.5,.5,.75,.75,.75,.99,.99,.99))
values <- (c(3.7,1.7,3.7,4.5,7.4,4.5,2.2,1.7,2.2))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(items,ordered,values))
df
```

Here is the ideal outcome:

```
Item 1,.5,1.7
Item 2,.75,4.5
Item 3,.99,2.2
```

Note that value 1.7 is not able to be selected for Item 3 (group 3) because it was already selected in Item 1.

I imagine this is some sort of for loop, but I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `library(tidyderse)`

```r
library(tidyverse)
items <- (c("item 1","item 1","item 1","item 2","item 2","item 2","item 3","item 3","item 3"))
ordered <- (c(.5,.5,.5,.75,.75,.75,.99,.99,.99))
values <- (c(3.7,1.7,3.7,4.5,7.4,4.5,2.2,1.7,2.2))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(items,ordered,values))

df %>% 
  distinct(values, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  group_by(items) %>% 
  slice_min(values)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   items [3]
#>   items  ordered values
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr> 
#> 1 item 1 0.5     1.7   
#> 2 item 2 0.75    4.5   
#> 3 item 3 0.99    2.2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Wowwww I did not know about `distinct` and `keep_all`.  Man.  I would not have thought to do it like this.  Brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop. For each `items` select the `min` `values` removing the minimum values selected from previous items.

```
vec <- unique(df$items)
result <- numeric(length(vec))

for(i in seq_along(vec)) {
  tmp <- df$values[df$items == vec[i]]
  result[i] <- min(tmp[!tmp %in% result], na.rm = TRUE)
}
cbind(unique(df[1:2]), result)

#   items ordered result
#1 item 1    0.50    1.7
#4 item 2    0.75    4.5
#7 item 3    0.99    2.2
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(items,ordered,values)
```

Comment: I explained this incorrectly and gave a bad example.  I just updated the example and expected output.  The groupings are meaningful.  I need to select the lowest number in value for each group, but I can't select the same value twice.